# handed down to them from teachers past - past - meaning

Tags: grammar

> If you were blessed with brilliant, enlightened teachers, your
>   experience with grammar has led you to understand not only
>   how to use it but also why it’s essential. However, because
>   you’re holding this book in your hands, I suspect that may not
>   have been the case. More likely, you were blessed with caring,
>   dedicated teachers who followed a pattern of instruction
>   handed down to them from teachers **past**. That pattern likely
>   focused on memorizing parts of speech and diagramming
>   sentences. And here you are, years later, trying to recall what
>   indirect objects are and why you should care.

First of all, is this word used as an adverb or adjective? And secondly, is my understanding that it talks about teachers from the past who were teaching the teachers who are now teaching you correct?

Comment: Hello Cookie, do you think you could go through your old questions and replace those that have only the grammar tag with tags that are more specific? Thanks :)

Comment: Oops, you have quite a few questions tagged "grammar" http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6450+%5Bgrammar%5D even retagging ten questions will help keep ELL more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is an adjective and your understanding is correct.